# Python regular expression: decimal part of float

Tags: python, regex

How can I accomplish the following transformations with a regular expression in Python?

```
0.44 -> 44
0.7867 -> 78
1.00 -> 100
```

Comment: Or, if there's other way do this, please give your opinions.

Comment: So many answers and there wasn't even a question!

Comment: Please mark your homework with [homework].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse the input as a floating point number then multiply it by 100 and truncate to an integer:

```
result = int(float(s) * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def twodigitint(x):
   return int(100*float(x))
```

(or use `round` instead of `int` if you really want 0.7867->79)

Answer (score 0):

How about *100 and convert to int

```
t = lambda x: int (x*100)
t(0.44)
```